# PayPal classic form with custom Dispatch details instead of "The seller hasn’t provided any dispatch details yet"

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using a PayPal classic Payments Standard form to send details to PayPal, as detailed here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#

When the purchaser pays they get an email receipt which has the following section:

> Dispatch details
>
> The seller hasn't provided any dispatch details yet.

Is it possible to change the text "The seller hasn't provided any dispatch details yet."? Is there a variable in the form that affects this text?